# How to import .css and .js files in JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

I know how to import, was not getting proper wording to ask this question.

So my question is, What is the difference between below two imports.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value='resources/scripts/jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js'/>"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is done so you can be sure the resources are referenced relative to the application context.
So you can be pretty sure if the file exists it will be found.

"The URL must be either an absolute URL starting with a scheme (e.g. "http:// server/context/page.jsp") or a relative URL as defined by JSP 1.2 in JSP.2.2.1 "Relative URL Specification". As a consequence, an implementation must prepend the context path to a URL that starts with a slash (e.g. "/page2.jsp") so that such URLs can be properly interpreted by a client browser."

Comment: Thanks @randomizer.... could you please redirect me to where I can found little more clarification on the same.

Comment: You can find more information here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_url_tag.htm and in the official docs.

Answer (score 1):

c:url tag transfers url into a string format and assigns in a variable.  It is an alternative method for response.encodeURL(). This tag automatically performs URL rewriting when necessary.
It has some attribute. They are as follows var, value, context,scope.

Whereas for ordinary import browser has to do these things. It is time consuming

Advantage of rewriting URL;

It is browser independent.